# how to disable "install missing plugins" error in firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, plugins

I'm using SoundManager2, so that audio files are played with flash if available, but through HTML5 audio if not. In Firefox, with Flash not installed, the audio files play perfectly.

However, there is an error shown anyway, saying "install missing plugins", even though the audio files do play properly without flash (and there is no other content that requires flash or any other plugin - I've replicated this with a blank HTML file and a single audio file).

Is there any way to make this error message go away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiding info bar "Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page" in Firefox:

**UPDATE:**

*(12/2013)*

- **for actual Firefox version**

  (> 25):

  1. open URL: `about:config`
  2. search `plugins.notifyMissingFlash`
  3. double-click on this entry and value should be changed from *false* to *true*.

---

- **for older Firefox versions**

  (< 24 probably):

  1. open URL: `about:config`
  2. search `plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin`
  3. double-click on this entry and value should be changed from *false* to *true*.

(this works for my Firefox 21)

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/936504

Comment: in newer versions it is `plugins.notifyMissingFlash`

Answer (score 0):

`plugins.notifyMissingFlash` doesn't have any effect when set to `false`.

I think it's a bug (documented here):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=917713